# Maven error - Glassfish vs Sun Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I am trying to setup a new web project to implement rest service using `Jetty` and `Jersey`. But I am getting errors while trying to define maven dependencies.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am getting lot of errors like these:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:
jetty-server:jar:9.2.5.v20141112

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:
jetty-server:jar:9.2.5.v20141112
```

However, using `com.sun.jersey` is working:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to which remote repository your are pointing but I am able to locate the jar at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.5.v20141112/

If you are using some other remote repo, try adding below repository as well.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```